# Cloth falls through object during simulation

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am fairly new to blender and I am having tons of trouble with a cloth simulation. I have subdivided cloth with the cloth physics modifier at stock settings and an object below it with the collision modifier but the cloth always falls through it. Here is the .blend file... help would be much appreciated, I'm getting so frustrated I kinda want to delete blender right now. Let me know if you need any more info, I am desperate to find a solution.

Pre simulation:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8AdR.jpg

Post Simulation:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZzLc.jpg

Collision object settings:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFQtN.jpg

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: You have to have collision enabled on both of the objects

Comment: I just tried enabling it on the cloth and it didn't make a difference...

Answer (score 1):

Hey i had the exact same problem you just have to remove the collision cube and make a new cube dont ctrl d

Comment: well it is a turtorial on how to make a room and i had the same problem and that was what i did and dont know why it works.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to untick "Single Sided"in the "Softbody and Cloth" menu of the mattress collision. At least it helped (until the next problem/question)